# Discord.js - counter of sent messages, DM to all members of guild

Tags: node.js, foreach, promise, discord.js, increment

So, I have a working example of code, that sends a DM to all members of a guild.
However, I want the whole thing to end with a message, sort of: "Successfully sent XX messages".

```
        const sentMessages = 0;
        if (!message.member.hasPermission(`ADMINISTRATOR`)) {
            message.channel.send(`You don't have permission to use this command!`);
            message.client.channels.cache.get(logchannel).send(`${message.author} tried using DMALL! ` + dato.toLocaleTimeString() + dato.toLocaleDateString());
            return;
        } else {
            const delay = (msec) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, msec));
            const sendMessage = args.join(" ");
            message.channel.send(`Sending messages, please wait...`);
            await delay(1000);
            let interval = 500; // how much time should the delay between two iterations be (in milliseconds)?
            let promise = Promise.resolve();
            message.guild.members.cache.forEach(function (user) {
                promise = promise.then(function () {
                    if (user.id != message.client.user.id) {
                        user.send(sendMessage);
                        sentMessages++;
                        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                            setTimeout(resolve, interval);
                        });
                    }
                });
                message.channel.send(`Successfully sent ${sentMessages} messages!`);
            });
```

The message at the end (Successfully...) keeps returning 0, no matter when or where I place it.
If I put a line like: **message.channel.send(`Sent: ${sentMessages});** below **sentMessages++;** I get an incrementing number like I expect.

What and where am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up turning to a friend who is much better at coding than me.
He came up with a totally different way of getting there:

```
        if (!message.member.hasPermission(`ADMINISTRATOR`)) {
            message.channel.send(`You don't have permission to use this command!`);
            message.client.channels.cache.get(logchannel).send(`${message.author} tried using DMALL in **${message.guild.name}**!` + dato.toLocaleTimeString() + dato.toLocaleDateString());
            return;
        } else {
            const delay = (msec) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, msec));
            const sendMessage = args.join(" ");
            message.channel.send(`Sending messages, please wait...`);
            await delay(1000);
            const interval = 500;
            let array;
            try {
                const all = await message.guild.members.fetch();
                array = all.array();
            } catch {
                array = message.guild.members.cache.array();
            }
            let sentMessages = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                const user = array[i];
                if (!user.bot) {
                    try {
                        await user.send(sendMessage);
                        sentMessages++;
                        await delay(interval);
                    } catch { }
                }
            }
            message.client.channels.cache.get(logchannel).send(`${message.author} sent a DM to all members of: **${message.guild.name}**!` + dato.toLocaleTimeString() + dato.toLocaleDateString());
            message.channel.send(`Finished sending messages to all users, ${sentMessages} messages sent!`);
        }
```

This code is tested and found to be working like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Use `let sentMessages = 0` instead of `const sentMessages = 0`

Constants can't be updated or reassigned, so `sentMessages++` won't do anything

Comment: I changed to let, but no change. Still saying 0 messages.
I also moved the sentMessages++; to outside the if() statement, to no avail.
```
            if (user.id != message.client.user.id) {
                        user.send(sendMessage);
                        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                            setTimeout(resolve, interval);
                        });
                    }
                    sentMessages++;
                });
                
            });
```
Still same result...

Comment: @Gier Maybe change ``let`` to ``var``? I'm stumped 

Comment: Yeah, I had the same idea, but same result...
I just can't figure this one out :/

Comment: Do you know if it's successfully sending the DMs either?

Comment: Yeah, the DMs are coming through to all users..?
I caved in and contacted a seasoned Discord.js friend and he came up with a code that is far superior to mine. I'll post it in a bit. Tested and found working ;)

Answer (score -1):

Just do not do this if you do not want to be bannes from Discord, it is forbidden to send private message to all members of a guild.